# Show level of loop in multidimensional array

Tags: php, loops, recursion, while-loop

i need help for this recursion.
i'm on php and i have this array tree

```
    Array
    (
        [14|Erboristeria e Salute] => Array
            (
                [15] => Mal di gola e Cavo orale
                [16] => Tosse e vie respiratorie
                [17] => Naso irritato
                [18] => Digestione e Gonfiore addominale
                [19] => Emorroidi
                [20] => Riposo notturno
                [21] => Tono ed Energia
                [22] => Controllo del peso
                [23] => Benessere delle Gambe e Cellulite
                [24] => Depurazione
                [25] => Pomate
                [37] => Dolori muscolari e Mal di testa
                [53] => Igiene orale
                [55] => Monoconcentrati
                [58] => Stomaco e Intestino
                [60] => Menopausa
                [65] => Occhi irritati
                [66] => Difese dell'organismo
                [84] => Caramelle
                [87] => Colesterolo e funzionalità cardiovascolare
                [88] => Tisane
                [127] => Succhi Attivi 100%
                [130] => Cistite
                [131] => Candida
            )

        [154|Prodotti per la casa] => Array
            (
                [38|Profumatori d'ambiente] => Array
                    (
                        [40] => Essenze naturali
                        [44] => Puri oli essenziali
                        [45] => Diffusori con bastoncini Nasoterapia
                        [85] => Profumatori Spray
                        [105] => Brucia essenze
                        [118] => Lampade catalitiche e ricariche
                        [133] => Buste profumate
                        [142] => Diffusori ultrasuoni
                        [149] => Ricariche diffusori con bastoncini
                        [150] => Diffusori in ceramica
                        [152] => Profumatori per auto
                        [153] => Profumatori L'Amande
                    )

                [68] => Candele per ambiente
                [109] => Candele Cilindriche
                [123] => Prodotti naturali anti zanzare
                [132] => Prodotti per la cura del cane
                [181] => Idee regalo
            )

        [155|Cosmesi e Igiene] => Array
            (
                [6|Cura del viso] => Array
                    (
                        [54] => Aspersina Pharmalife - Bava di lumaca
                        [57|Linee Innoxa] => Array
                            (
                                [165] => Per pulire e stimolare
                                [166] => Linea idratazione giorno
                                [167] => Linea Autentica - rigenerante anti radicale
                                [168] => Super nutrimento con RNA e Omega3
                                [169] => Linea 41- pelle grassa, impura, acneica
                                [170] => Linea Couprosil - pelle sensibile e couperose
                                [171] => PG 33 - trattamento anti rughe
                                [172] => Linea Collagene - ritarda invecchiamento
                                [173] => Linea Naga - con sericina effetto tensore
                                [175] => Trattamenti intensivi rigeneranti
                            )

                        [61] => Contorno occhi
                        [63] => Pulizia Viso
                        [75] => Linea Olio Argan
                        [101] => Egasi Visage Amerigo
                        [102] => L'Amande Viso
                        [116] => Hyaluronic Bio Amerigo
                        [146] => Linea Activo 3 Oficine Cleman
                        [176] => Goji Bio Amerigo
                        [177] => Prodotti Flora Pisa
                        [178] => Viso Oficine Cleman
                        [179] => Acido Jaluronico
                    )

                [7|Cura dei Capelli] => Array
                    (
                        [82] => Capelli con forfora
                        [98] => Capelli normali
                        [99] => Trattamenti capelli
                        [100] => Pediculosi
                        [134] => Capelli lisci
                        [135] => Capelli ricci e mossi
                        [136] => Capelli colorati
                        [137] => Capelli secchi e sfibrati
                        [138] => Capelli delicati e lavaggi frequenti
                        [139] => Capelli grassi e pesanti
                        [140] => Anti caduta capelli
                        [143] => Balsamo
                        [144] => Gel per capelli
                    )

                [8|Cura del corpo] => Array
                    (
                        [29] => Igiene Intima
                        [30] => Cellulite e Tono Muscolare
                        [32] => Acque Profumate
                        [33|Creme corpo] => Array
                            (
                                [156] => Creme Corpo L'Amande
                                [157] => Creme Corpo Amerigo
                                [158] => Creme Corpo Speziali Fiorentini
                                [159] => Creme Corpo Oficine Cleman
                                [161] => Creme Corpo Flora Pisa
                                [162] => Creme Corpo Innoxa
                                [187] => Creme Dr Organic
                            )

                        [34] => Deodoranti
                        [36] => Oli vegetali corpo
                        [43] => Scrub
                        [77] => Prodotti per Ceretta
                        [160] => Oli profumati per il corpo
                    )

                [9] => Prodotti per l'uomo
                [10|Solari] => Array
                    (
                        [78] => Solari Innoxa
                        [79] => Solari L'Amande
                        [103] => Solari Amerigo
                        [180] => Solari Oficine Cleman
                    )

                [11] => Saponi vegetali e Detergenti liquidi
                [12|Prodotti per il bagno] => Array
                    (
                        [96] => Bagnoschiuma
                    )

                [13|Cura delle mani] => Array
                    (
                        [62] => Cura e Igiene Mani
                        [104] => Crema per le mani
                    )

                [26|Profumi] => Array
                    (
                        [125] => Eau de Parfum
                    )

                [27] => Prodotti per i bambini
                [28] => Cura dei piedi
                [49|Trucchi e Make Up] => Array
                    (
                        [50] => Rossetti Hydrating
                        [51] => Fondotinta
                        [52] => Ombretti
                        [81] => Smalti Innoxa
                        [92] => Lucida Labbra
                        [93] => Rossetto Fluido
                        [95] => Rosso Labbra Soft Touche
                        [117] => Mascara
                        [121] => Fard
                        [141] => Creme colorate viso
                        [186] => Rossetti Color Lip finish luxury Mat
                    )

                [59|Tinture per capelli] => Array
                    (
                        [128] => Naturidea
                        [147] => Henne in polvere
                        [184] => Mascara Henne
                    )

                [76] => L'Amande Eco Bio
                [83] => Candele da massaggio
                [94] => Stick Labbra
                [182] => Sapone Marino Naclean
            )

    )
```

I need to insert this array into db with hierarchical system.
So for example **14|Erboristeria e Salute** has level 1 and **Mal di gola e Cavo orale** has level 2

In the same way **154|Prodotti per la casa** has level 1, **38|Profumatori d'ambiente** has level 2 and **Essenze naturali** has level 3......then **Candele per ambiente** has level 2!

How can i do that? I have wrote this function and it works but i can't figure out how can i set level!

```
    function readDeep($nodo)
    {
        foreach ($nodo as $k=>$v)
        { 

            if (is_array($v))
            {
                echo "<div style='border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:2em'>";
                echo "<b>".$k." </b>";
                echo "<br />";
                readDeep($v);
                echo "</div>";

            }
            else
            {   
                echo $v;
                echo "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the level to the function, you can default it for the first level and then pass the value back in when you do the recursion.  So the definition becomes...

```
function readDeep($nodo, $level = 1)
```

And then the recursion becomes...

```
readDeep($v, $level+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an extra parameter to your recursive function representing the level. When you first call it, pass in 0 (or 1, according to taste), then when calling it recursively add one:

```
function readDeep($nodo, $level=0) {
    // ...
    readDeep($v, $level+1);
    // ...
}
```